# PowerShell Set-WebApplication property bag doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have this PowerShell script

```
function SetPropertyBag ($webAppUrl, $key, $value) {

    $spwebApp=Get-SPWebApplication -Identity $webAppUrl
    Write $spwebApp  

    if($spwebApp.Properties.ContainsKey($key) -eq $False)
    {
        $spwebApp.Properties.Add($key,$value);        
    }
    else
    {$spwebApp.Properties[$key]=$value; }

    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "value set in "  $key  " = "  $spwebApp.Properties[$key]    

    }

$webAppUrl= Read-Host 'Enter the web application url';
$siteCollectionUrl= Read-Host 'Enter the site collection url';
SetPropertyBag $webAppUrl "VGSP.VIS.TicketTale.EngineJob" $siteCollectionUrl ;
```

It's working great on PowerShell but when i try to get the property bag value by server side code I don't find.

I also deployed the property bag settings solution and didn't find the values that I've set there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$spwebApp.Properties.Add($key,$value);
$spwebApp.Update();
```

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Hashtable] doesn't contain a method named 'Update'.
At C:\Users\Alshimaa\Desktop\PropertyBagSetter.ps1:19 char:32
+     $spwebApp.Properties.Update <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Update:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: It is actually recomanded to use AllProperties instead as Properties is only maintained for back-compatibility purposes and is obsolete!

Comment: Thanks @c-marius, updated the answer to use AllProperties

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. Solution:

```
$spwebApp.Update();
```

The solution suggested by eirikb does not work because:

1. The SPWebApplication object does not have a property called "AllProperties".
2. It does have a property called "Properties" (as written by the OP), however this property does not have an Update() method.

(Note: I'm using SP2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can set property bag value using power shell and the same can be retrievable from C# code with the help of unique **Key**.

Below is the link, where it had explained to set property bag value and retrieve the same.
http://himanshu214.blogspot.in/2015/10/powershell-set-property-bag-to.html